# Animation duration having no effect in WPF RotateTransform

Tags: wpf

I am unable to get a RotateTransform to animate smoothly in WPF. I've been able to reproduce the behvior using the following simple application where a button rotates back and forth between 0 and 180 degrees.

My MainWindow.xaml code is the following:

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Button x:Name="testButton" Content="Test" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Window>
```

And the code-behind file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    RotateTransform testButtonRotateTransform;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.8, 0.8);
        testButtonRotateTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
        transformGroup.Children.Add(scaleTransform);
        transformGroup.Children.Add(testButtonRotateTransform);
        testButton.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        testButton.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(testButtonRotateTransform.Angle == 0)
        {
            DoubleAnimation angleRotationAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
                            0, 
                            180,
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(250)));

            testButtonRotateTransform.BeginAnimation(
                            RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
                            angleRotationAnimation);
        }

        else
        {
            DoubleAnimation angleRotationAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
                            180, 
                            0, 
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds(250)));

            testButtonRotateTransform.BeginAnimation(
                            RotateTransform.AngleProperty, 
                            angleRotationAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this example and click on the button, it does rotate as expected. However, the rotation is not animated, it snaps to the terminal angles rather than smoothly rotating over 250ms and I can't figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm using VS2022 Community and targeting .NET 8.0.

Comment: You wanted to write `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` instead of `TimeSpan.FromMicroseconds`. There is also too much duplicate code in the Click handler. Write something like `var targetAngle = testButtonRotateTransform.Angle == 0 ? 180 : 0;`, then create and run the animation with that value. There is no need to specify the `From` value of the animation, `To` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. That silly mistake ("Microseconds" vs "Milliseconds") was indeed the problem. Too much reliance on intellisense.